# google map; client id; must you have one AND $$$$

Tags: google-maps

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/guide

Just want to familiarize myself with the api... just do a little hacking.

Are you required to obtain a Client ID?.  It appears so.  But then I see they charge, or will charge, for exceeding very generous access limits.  Does this mean I have to protect my client id?

If registering URLs is the only thing required, then do you guys go back and delete them?

I just want to play with it on my godaddy account.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the page you provided states:

> you **must** provide a client ID when accessing any of the API libraries or services

so yeah, you need a client ID, but it also states that

> This client ID is not a key. It will only work from URLs which you
>   authorize so **you don't need to worry about keeping it secret**.

so no, you don't really need to protect it.

Maybe that very same page will provide you with other useful info you require